# How to zoom out/resize font on Microsoft Word documents?

Tags: 8.1, office-hub, word

Is there a way to resize the whole document to a smaller font in order to have it fit in my screen without looking weird or unreadable because of tables and indents?

The best way I've found so far is to convert specific docs to pdf in order to read them comfortably when I'm not on a PC, but I'd much rather not have to do this.

I'm using the default "Office" from Microsoft to view the documents on my Lumia 920 with Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the text you want to change (If it's already typed. Otherwise, do this before typing). At the bottom right, tap Format, then, under format, tap the button with an A and a down arrow in it. This will downsize your font. Do this as many times as necessary to make it look how you want.